# Prettier doesn't support private methods despite claiming to

Tags: typescript, prettier

According to [#5660](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5660), prettier supports private methods and properties. But when I run it on a TypeScript file that has private methods and properties, it complains that it doesn't.

Command:

```sh
npx prettier "src/web-components/registerCustomElement.tsx"
```

.prettierrc.yml:

```yaml
trailingComma: es5
tabWidth: 4
semi: false
singleQuote: true
arrowParens: avoid
printWidth: 80
importOrder:
  - "^@"
  - "^(?!src|\\.)"
  - "^.+"
importOrderSeparation: true
overrides:
  - files:
    - "*.json"
    options:
      tabWidth: 2
```

src/web-components/registerCustomElement.tsx:

```js
import type { ComponentType } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

type Args = {
    name: string
    attributes: string[]
    component: ComponentType<unknown>
}

/**
 * Register a custom element which wraps a React component.
 *
 * @param name       - the name of the custom element
 * @param attributes - the names of the custom element's attributes
 * @param component  - the React component
 */
export default function registerCustomElement({ name, attributes, component: Component }: Args) {
    const webComponentClass = class extends HTMLElement {
        readonly #mountPoint: HTMLElement
        readonly #shadowRoot: ShadowRoot

        constructor() {
            super()
            this.#mountPoint = document.createElement('div')
            this.#shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
        }

        connectedCallback() {
            if (this.isConnected) {
                const attrs = attributes.reduce((acc, key) => Object.assign(acc, { [key]: this.getAttribute(key) }), {})

                this.#shadowRoot.appendChild(this.#mountPoint)
                ReactDOM.render(<Component {...attrs} />, this.#mountPoint)
            }
        }

        disconnectedCallback() {
            if (!this.isConnected) {
                this.#shadowRoot.removeChild(this.#mountPoint)
            }
        }
    }

    customElements.define(name, webComponentClass)
}
```

Result:

```
src/web-components/registerCustomElement.tsx[error] src/web-components/registerCustomElement.tsx: SyntaxError: This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): 'classPrivateProperties, classPrivateMethods' (19:17)
```

Comment: The workaround is to use `private` instead of `#`. I was using `#` because `shadowRoot` already exists on `HTMLElement`. However, I since discovered that `attachShadow` sets `shadowRoot`, so I'm using `private` instead of `#`. Nevertheless, it would be nice to know if/how this is supported in prettier.

Comment: You can achieve this by using the plugins that are mentioned in the error statement. See the PRs for the features: [Add support for class private methods](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/5637/files#diff-20c49ec587666e7fdf5b3853ff2309009e76bbd9a66f277d013616396e52c6cbR38) and [Add support for ClassPrivateProperty](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/2837/files#diff-d3062363e56df7149006de9c1c70b7134cd4d268e4e7100ee850af9d87b97f78R29)